# How do you reverse tunnel to a different local ip

Tags: remote-desktop, openvpn, raspberry-pi, reverse-tunnel, motion

I have a reverse tunnel following this answer... [How to get a persistent reverse SSH tunnel using autossh?](https://superuser.com/questions/1046231/how-to-get-a-persistent-reverse-ssh-tunnel-using-autossh/1046235#1046235)
Both ends are RaspberryPis. MotionEyeOS is on a eero router with no routing options and a dynamic IP.
The other router has a fixed ip with iptables where I can assign ports and it is running RaspianOS32 at 192.168.1.87.

I can open a webpage and access the Motioneye by running this command on the remote pi by traversing the tunnel with:

```
ssh admin@localhost -vvv -p 43022
```

Then I run this on the MotionEyeOS pi:

```
autossh -M 0 -R 43089:localhost:80 pi@172.x.y.z -p8887
```

I added a `-L` on the initial tunnel to try to RDP back to a laptop at 192.168.4.29.

```
autossh -M 0 -L 43087:192.168.4.29:3389 pi@172.x.y.z -p8887 -R 43022:localhost:22 pi@172.x.y.z -p8887
```

It doesn't complain or work.
MotionEyeOS is a read only file system. You have limited access. I did add a shell script at `/data/output` but `/etc/rc.local` can not be created.

MotionEyeOS does have IPtables.
I looked at PIVPN but MotionEye doesnt have it. Can I setup IP tables so that the -L section comes through as local host but gets port forward to 192.168.4.29 similar to openvpn but only to the IP I specify.

Comment: 172.X.y.z isn’t a public IP Address….why are you sanitizing it?

Comment: Either they didn't know that...or it might be a public IP address in their case. 172.X.y.z is a public address for values of X within [0, 15] or [32, 255] – only X in [16, 31] are private addresses.